# deploying angularjs to heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku, deployment

I have the following folder structure:
[image]

when I run `grunt serve` and `node serve.js` in my terminal, the app is running perfectly fine on localhost. 
However, when deployed to heroku, the app shows up but it runs as if the `node server.js` was not run on terminal when running localhost. Meaning that there is not interaction with the backend.

my server.js is like:

```
var express = require ('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./app/models/User.js');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google');
var request = require('request');
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:mypassword@ds123456.mlab.com:123456/mydb');

app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('api listening on', server.address().port);
});
app.use(morgan('dev'));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
})
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

  next();
})

var strategyOptions = {
  usernameField: 'email'
};

var loginStrategy = new LocalStrategy(strategyOptions, function (email, password, done) {

  var searchUser = {
    email: email
  };
  User.findOne(searchUser, function (err, user) {
    if(err) return done(err);

    if(!user) return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong email/password'});

    user.comparePasswords(password, function (err, isMatch) {
      if(err) return done(err);

      if(!isMatch)
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong email/password'});

      return done(null, user);
    });
  })

});

var registerStrategy = new LocalStrategy(strategyOptions, function (email, password, done) {
  var searchUser = {
    email: email
  };
  User.findOne(searchUser, function (err, user) {
    if(err) return done(err);
    //needs to be fixed on frontend
    if(user) return done(null, false, {message: 'This email is already registered'});

    var newUser = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });

    newUser.save(function (err) {
      done(null, newUser);
    })
  });
});

passport.use('local-register', registerStrategy);
passport.use('local-login', loginStrategy);

app.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-register'), function (req, res) {
  createSendToken(req.user, res);
})
//and a number of code managing the other signup functions
```

and the procfile is:

```
web: node server.js
```

and the package.json is:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nf start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
```

Comment: Is there anything helpful in logs from Heroku?